# AirPlay Button Custom Sizing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an Airplay Button which I have created by subclassing a UIButton to AVRoutePickerView in Storyboard. It's showing the button and also showing the view when tapped. I am unsure how I can change the size of the icon though. Have I created the Airplay Button incorrectly or am I just missing something?

Comment: Could you post your custom button class code here?

Comment: @RazibMollick I’m just using the stock class at the moment and haven’t written any extra code in it.

Comment: Without seeing some code, it's hard to tell how you are setting the image but Apple recommends using edge insets specifically for the image in a button: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624034-imageedgeinsets.  This could not be the correct answer for you b/c I may be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @TimD I’m not setting any image. Just setting the class of the button and it’s adding the image itself

Comment: @mink23 alright to quote the documentation then: "Use insets to add or remove space around the content in your custom or system buttons." Even if it is a system button or a button that is subclassed to whatever, it sounds like they want you to use the inset properties. But the documentation specifically for the button : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avroutepickerviewbuttonstyle/custom even setting it to "custom", there does not seem to be publicly available properties to make those buttons larger at least from my understanding of their documentation.

Comment: @TimD It's strange because I have no insets set. I've set the width and height of the button to 44px yet it's showing about half that size.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to use a UIButton.  An AVRoutePickerView is a UIView, not a UIButton.  It creates a UIButton and inserts it as a subview of itself.  That's the button you want to resize.

You can access AVRoutePickerView's button by doing this hackery:

```
let button = routePickerView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIButton }) as? UIButton
```

You can then experiment with changing its frame size... maybe directly or via constraints.

Just beware that this hackery isn't future-proof.  Apple could change how it manages the button in the future.